# Run Time error in Excel while opening excel workbook (-2147221080)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

My macro gets stuck during run. I am getting run time error screenshot attached below.
[image: Error while running]

when i debugged the code , i am getting "can't execute in break mode" this popup coming repeatedly.
Could someone can help me out on this issue?

I couldn't see any syntax error in my code, during debug pop up comes on during opening the excel workbook.

Comment: Does the workbook being opened contain any auto-running macros?

Comment: No there is no auto running macros

Comment: What line is highlighted when you click "Debug"?  Make sure you have your VBA error settings on "Break in class module"